# very simple selenium auto-click for webpage does not work

Tags: selenium

I am very new.
I was trying to make an auto mail sender for practice.
It opens website but not the login button.
There is nothing happen after it opened.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='/Users/aidencho/practice/chromedriver', options = options)

# open a website    
url = 'https://naver.com'
driver.get(url)

# driver.maximize_window()
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.link_login').click()
# driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#account > a").click()
# driver.find_element_by_class_name('.account > a').click()
```

One more thing.
I saw someone doing this, and there was a completed sentence for driver.find_element_by_css_selector part even he typed only driver.find.
Why not me?
Would there be a setting problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh9pw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find_element_by_css_selector is deprecated. Please use find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector) instead.

```
driver.find_element(by="css selector", value='.link_login')
```